# MSRA.exe not connecting from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, cmd

When running the following code in the `PowerShell ISE` the `Windows Remote Assistance` window pops-up but it keeps showing the message:

> Connecting to the remote computer to get logged in users...

```
$Computer = 'PC1'

$WinRemAss = "$env:systemroot/system32/msra.exe"
Start-Process $WinRemAss -ArgumentList "/OfferRA $Computer"
```

When using the CMD prompt, this works fine:

```
msra /offerra PC1
```

Is there a way to have it also function in from within PowerShell?

Comment: Thx Matt, but I guess there's something wrong with your syntax as it pops-up the help page on how to use parameters...

Comment: @DarkLite1 `& $WinRemAss "/OfferRA",$Computer` - what exactly happens when it "works fine"? I get the same behavior using both `&`, `Start-Process` and when invoking it directly

Comment: Thx Mathias, your syntax is correct. But it's still not connecting. From the CMD prompt it connects in a second, but not from within PowerShell. Is there a way to start `CMD` in PowerShell to launch `msra` from there as a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following three statements are equivalent and should produce the same results:

```
Start-Process $WinRemAss -ArgumentList "/OfferRA $Computer" -Wait -NoNewWindow
& $WinRemAss /OfferRA $Computer
cmd /c $WinRemAss /OfferRA $Computer
```

Comment: Thank you Ansgar, only the last statement works. And this one `Start-Process cmd.exe -ArgumentList "/C msra /offerra $Computer" -NoNewWindow`